# How do I add data from ListBox into SQL Server database in C# Windows forms?

Tags: c#, listbox

I am working on a project where the user gets to generate a set of licenses keys and export it into a text file. The information is then displayed in a listbox as shown below. I am using C# and Windows Forms:

[image]

On top of this I would also like to save the details from the listbox into the local SQL Server database for record keeping purposes in my application. I have tried out various methods I found online to do this but all were unsuccessful.

One of the methods I've found is from this link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUZGyA6UKGI&t=0s&index=26&list=PLZEMJ7iJtVdq9aMAiDfRlMoNrzGaWOfkZ

Here is the code I used from the video tutorial:

```
private void recordinserted(List<string>li)
{
        StringBuilder stringbi = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);

        foreach (string item in li)
        {
            const string qry = "Insert into [LicenseDB](Comapny Name, Software Name, LicenseKeys)values";
            stringbi.AppendFormat("{0}('{i}');",qry,item);
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Documents\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = stringbi.ToString();
        cmd.Connection = con;

        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (a > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("inserted");
        }
}

// adding into local database (method placed in button click)
List<string> li = new List<string>();

foreach (ListViewItem item in lbGeneratedKeys.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        li.Add(item.Text);
    }

    recordinserted(li);
}
```

I realized that the person was using C# with ASP.Net and makes use of ListITem property which Windows Form does not have.

The other method I used is the classic `SqlConnection` method:

```
//adding into local database
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Documents\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LicenseDB (Company Name, Software Name, LicenseKeys,LicenseFileNo) VALUES (@cName, @sName, @lKeys, @lno)");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        lbGeneratedKeys.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        lbGeneratedKeys.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
        lbGeneratedKeys.Items.Add(dr[2].ToString());
        lbGeneratedKeys.Items.Add(dr[3].ToString());
    }
}
```

I used (`dr[0].ToString()`) to read each line from the listbox to be added into the database, where each number represents a row in the listbox. Eg. [0] represents the company name in the listbox. However when I try to execute the program there's an error saying that the `SqlDataReader` row is not initialized.

Also, since my program has the algorithm for users to generate more than one license keys, I also need help on how I can group these several rows of generated license keys to be added into one database column in the Database table. For instance in my UI above, I chose to generate 3 license keys and each license key takes up a row in the ListBox, I would like to group these three rows together to be placed under one database column variable (licenseKeys). I would like the algorithm to be able to read the generated keys dynamically as well as the user can generate as many license keys as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred back to my previous school project and managed to save my listbox data into the SQL database. I have two listboxes in total: 1 for allowing user to export as text file, and the second to specifically store generated license keys only. The second listbox is set to not visible in my program.

The codes I used:

```
 private void exportKey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //adding into local database
        //excludes adding licensekeys
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Documents\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("addLicensedata", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"companyName", companyTextbox.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"softwareName", softwareTextbox.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"prodID", prodidTextbox.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"licenseType", cbLicensetype.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"LicenseNo", licensekeyNum.Text.Trim()); //no of license keys 

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //MessageBox.Show("Added to database");
        sqlCon.Close();

        if (cbLicensetype.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Trial")
        {
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"TrialDays", tbTrialdays.Text.Trim());
        }

        addtoFKtable();

private void addtoFKtable()
    {
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Documents\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        Con.Open();
        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("addLicensekeys", Con);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"LicenseNo", licensekeyNum.Text.Trim());
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"LicenseKeys", lbHidden.Text.Trim());
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"prodID", prodidTextbox.Text.Trim());
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"companyName", companyTextbox.Text.Trim());
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //MessageBox.Show("Added license to database");
        Con.Close();
    }
```

I stored my SQL commands as a stored procedure within the database, and just called the command in my codes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I had understood your problem:

First of all, I think is very important to define your data model. For example, in order to allow that a user can define a lot of keys, I would use another table where all the keys were stored, after that you need to define if a same key could be related to more than one row on the table 'LicenseDB' (in the table 'LicenseDB' you would have the columns Company Name, Software Name, LicenseFileNo). If so you'd have the relation (n:n) and then you would need to build another intermediate table that defines the relation between the table 'keys' and the table 'LicenseDB' . If it's not the case, then you simple define the relation between 'keys' and 'LicenseDB' (n:1) adding a column licenseDbID to the table 'keys' that relation many keys to one row in the table 'LicenseDB'

On the other hand, the problem with your code is that you are trying to insert data and not to read data, so you don't need a DataReader instead of that you just simply could implement something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection('YOUR STRING CONNECTION'))
     {
        con.Open();

        string comando = "INSERT INTO LicenseDB (companie, software) VALUES ('" + lbGeneratedKeys.Items[0].ToString() + "','" + lbGeneratedKeys.Items[1].ToString() + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = comando;

        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     }
```

In this case, two values are inserted into the table LicenseDB the values for companie name and software name.

I hope I had helped you.

Comment: Let me summarize what you're saying. So I should create a separate table where only the keys are stored and link it to the main database table? I am still not sure how I can define if license keys can take up more than one row in the listbox. Would appreciate if I can have a sample code on how I can define. @Carlos Pozos

Comment: As for the codes you provided, I received an error at the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery line saying that there is Incorrect syntax near 'Name'

Comment: That's correct. If you have, let's say 4 keys on the lsitbox, you need to get them with c# code then  you insert into the table LicenseDB the values for Company, Software and LicenseFileNo, then you get the ID for that row that you inserted into LicenseDB, let's say the id 3. After all of this, you need to insert the keys values into the table 'keys' put the id 3 on the column LicenseDBID. Each one would have the same LicenseDBID, in that way you stored as many keys as you want ant they are link to a Company Name, a Software Name and a LicenseFileNo.

Comment: The problem that gives you could be because the command 'insert into LicenseDB' could be different depending on your data model or the names of your columns on your data base. Try to debug your code: copy the string variable 'comando', put it into your DBMS, execute it and find out what is the problem,

Comment: I created another table to store the license keys specially and linked it to the primary table with foreign key. I created another listbox (hidden) and set it such that it only displays the license keys generated, and the main listbox (in the question) to only allow the user to export as text file. I managed to save the data into the database, thanks for your explanation!